# IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class Functions.size

Tags: java, enums, processing, illegalargumentexception

Given the following code:

```
enum Functions
{
  background,clear,colorMode,fill,noFill,noStroke,stroke,applyMatrix,popMatrix,
  printMatrix,pushMatrix,resetMatrix,rotate,rotateX,rotateY,rotateZ,scale,shearX,shearY,
  translate,ellipseMode,smooth,noSmooth,rectMode,strokeCap,strokeJoin,strokeWeight,arc,ellipse,
  line,point,quad,rect,triangle,size,frameRate;
}

switch(Functions.valueOf(f))
{  
   case background:
     //background()
     background(random(255),random(255),random(255));
     break;
   case clear:
     //clear()
     break;
   case colorMode:
     //colorMode()
     break;
   case fill:
     //fill()
     fill(random(255),random(255),random(255));
     break;
   case size:
     //size()
     break;
   .....
}
```

This is running fine most of the time, and no other Enum const has been throwing this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class Functions.size
```

But for some reason, Functions.size will sometimes cause this error to be thrown. Does anyone know why this might be happening intermittently?

Comment: on a sidenote, enum is not part of the Processing API, it's Java syntax that only works when Processing source is converted for JVM use.

Comment: can you create a minimal working example that shows this happening?

Comment: Fixed:Malformed strings that were being retrieved from a database file were causing the issue. This was solved by trimming the string before passing it the switch case.